# Pythonic conditions in dictionary and dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Say a have a superclass SuperClass and two children classes ClassA and ClasseB:

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self,superAttribute):
        self.superAttribute = superAttribute

class ClassA(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self,superAttribute,attributeA):
        self.attributeA = attributeA

class ClassB(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self,superAttribute,attributeB):
        self.attributeB = attributeB
```

Now I have a list of ClassA and ClassB objects `aBList` and I want to create a dictionary as follows:

```
aBDict = {}
for aB in aBList:
    aBDict['aKey'] = aB.attributeA # if aB has an attributeA attribute 
    aBDict['bKey'] = aB.attributeB # if aB has an attributeB attribute
```

In other words, as it's the case with list comprehension, is there a Pythonic dictionary comprehension that would use the classic if structure?

Comment: Your expected output isn't clear

Comment: Can't you use `isinstance(aB, ClassA)`?

Comment: Also note that `aBDict['aKey'] = ...` in a `for` loop will only keep the last value you set... probably not what you are aiming for.